# Datetime parser function keeps returning days on Tuesday

Tags: javascript

For some reason, my datetime parser keeps returning dates as Tuesday, any idea why?

**For Example:**

```
<div class="datetime">2015-06-04 16:00:00</div>
<div class="datetime">2015-06-05 13:00:00</div>
```

Output

```
Tuesday 04 June - 16:00
Tuesday 05 June - 13:00
```

**Code**

HTML

```
<div class="datetime">2015-06-04 16:00:00</div>
<div class="datetime">2015-06-05 13:00:00</div>
```

JS

```
$('.datetime').each(function () {
    var value  = $(this).text().trim().split(' '),
    date   = value[1].split(':'),
    day    = value[0].split('-'),
    days   = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'],
    months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
    date.pop();
    $(this).html(days[new Date(Date.parse('2015-05-04')).getDay()] +' '+day[2]+' '+ months[new Date(Date.parse(value[0])).getMonth()] + ' - ' + date[0] + ':' + date[1]);  
});
```

**Jsfiddle Link**

http://jsfiddle.net/bh5s7jdt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given hard coded date! change it to : `value[0]`

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/bh5s7jdt/1/)

```
$(this).html(days[new Date(Date.parse(value[0])).getDay()] +' '+day[2]+' '+   
  months[new Date(Date.parse(value[0])).getMonth()] + ' - ' + date[0] + ':' + date[1]);
```